# I want get month from date that save in data base . How is it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the month from a date that is saved in data base.

```
 int date = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ddate"].ToString());
```

Comment: What is the type of column in your database, if It is `DateTime`, then just get/convert your database value to `DateTime`  in C#, Later you can assess the month with `DateTime.Month` property.

Comment: Use DATEPART() in the query

Comment: my data base type is date

Comment: Please post your commandText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your date format is `'yyyy-MM-dd'`

```
int month = DateTime.Parse(dr["ddate"].ToString()).Month;
```